# Setting a JTable size to not have blank space

Tags: java, swing, jtable

When I make a JTable; I have the columns, and a single row, and then beneath that I have space for ~20 more rows, more if I increase the window size. I cannot have less as if I reduce the window size I just get a vertical scroll bar.

What I would like to do is make it so that the JTable size only goes to the last row.

I thought something like this:

```
newTable.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, (newTable.getRowCount() + 1) * newTable.getRowHeight()));
```

But this does absolutely nothing. Using setPreferred size instead makes a white background about one row bigger, but the actual table is still the same size.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqwFP.png

I also tried the same things on the scrollpane that the JTable is in, setting the max / min sizes did nothing, setting the preferred size allowed me to make the table smaller by resizing the window, so I'm guessing that I may be able to do what I want using this and a layout perhaps? But I get class cast exceptions when trying to give a layout to the scrollpane. So I'm unsure what to do.

Comment: You want to display only a single row?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I want to display as many rows as I have, if I only have one then the table should be the size necessary to only show one row

Comment: This isn't really how `JTable` or `JScrollPane` work

Comment: @MadProgrammer I managed to do it by setting the prefSize of the JTable container to 0 (and the same height) instead of max integer. and then setting the maxSize to max integer and the same height.

Comment: The preferred size of a `JScrollPane` is defined either by the `preferredSize` of the view component if it doesn't implement `Scrollable` or `getPreferredViewportSize` if it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `preferredSize` of the container that the JTable is in, ie. the scrollpane